# use of Mongo/Redis on a full firehose stream

Tags: mongodb, redis

I have been reading up on how DataSift uses different technologies to consume the twitter firehose and since I need to follow the same concept, wanted to get some understanding on the differences between mongo/redis and its use in storage of realtime data. My understanding is this:
The stream volume is way too high to simply consume and place the data (tweets etc) in for example a rabbitmq bunch of queues. My concern is the issue of data loss. My current architecture involves connecting to an open stream and consume the data and push each post or message into a couple of queues in rabbitmq. The queues hold a copy of each message with one being the processing queue and one being the storage queue. I then consume each queue by doing processing on the processing queue which is time intensive but my workers keep up fine and write all the storage queue contents to files and that works fine.

If my volume was to increase 100x, I am told this current setup will not be able to handle the volume and using the mongo/redis approach would be better. So not sure how this would be implemented: would I then consume the stream into mongo and then from there into queues and why would this be a better approach.

Comment: Have you looked at Storm?